# How do I change a list of lists to key, value?

Tags: python, csv

I want to convert the data as such:
the first row in csv are keys, the following rows are values. How can I do this?

So I want the keys to be 'SkuPartNumber', 'ActiveUnits', 'ConsumedUnits', and values to be the rows below it.

The goal being I can query records as per below and store the values elsewhere.

```
for i in records:
 ...
 results.append((i['SkuPartNumber'],i['ActiveUnits'],i['ConsumedUnits'])
```

Code:

```
>>>cmd = ['C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe', 'script.ps1']
>>>subprocess.call(cmd)
>>> with open ('sku.csv', 'r') as sku:
...     reader = csv.reader(sku)
...     records = list(reader)
...
>>> type(records)
<class 'list'>
>>> pprint(records)
[['SkuPartNumber', 'ActiveUnits', 'ConsumedUnits'],
 ['EXCHANGESTANDARD', '1', '1'],
 ['O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM', '4', '4']]
>>>
```

Appreciate some help.

Expected outcome:

```
[{
    "SkuPartNumber": "EXCHANGESTANDARD",
    "ActiveUnits": 1,
    "ConsumedUnits": 1
}, {
    "SkuPartNumber": "O365_Business_Premium",
    "ActiveUnits": 4,
    "ConsumedUnits": 4
}]
```

Comment: Input, expected output and less talk about irrelevant stuff like subprocesses please.

Comment: Input = [['SkuPartNumber', 'ActiveUnits', 'ConsumedUnits'],
 ['EXCHANGESTANDARD', '1', '1'],
 ['O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM', '4', '4']]

Output = [{
 "SkuPartNumber": "EXCHANGESTANDARD",
 "ActiveUnits": 1,
 "ConsumedUnits": 1
}, {
 "SkuPartNumber": "O365_Business_Premium",
 "ActiveUnits": 4,
 "ConsumedUnits": 4
}]

Comment: use [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you brought subprocesses, powershell and other topics into this, but what you need is a `DictReader` from the `csv` module.

```
>>> from csv import DictReader
>>> filedata = '''SkuPartNumber,ActiveUnits,ConsumedUnits
... EXCHANGESTANDARD,1,1
... O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM,4,4
... '''
>>> list(DictReader(filedata.splitlines()))
[{'ActiveUnits': '1', 'ConsumedUnits': '1', 'SkuPartNumber': 'EXCHANGESTANDARD'}, {'ActiveUnits': '4', 'ConsumedUnits': '4', 'SkuPartNumber': 'O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM'}]
```

In your actual code, just use `list(DictReader(f))` where `f` is the name of the opened file.

Comment: Apologies for giving some background, I'll try to be more direct in the future. Thanks for the tip for 'DictReader'

Comment: @oj43085 no problem. Giving context is good, but only when it is relevant. When in doubt, giving too much context is better than giving not enough. If any of the answers solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
records = [['SkuPartNumber', 'ActiveUnits', 'ConsumedUnits'],
           ['EXCHANGESTANDARD', '1', '1'],
           ['O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM', '4', '4']]


recorddictlist = [dict(SkuPartNumber=r[0],
                       ActiveUnits=r[1],
                       ConsumedUnits=r[2]) for r in records[1:]]

print(recorddictlist)
```

This isn't the most flexible, but assuming the output of your subprocess is stable I find it the easiest to read.

Otherwise you could use a `csv.DictReader` as in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
# new empty list of records in new format
transformed_records = []

# iterate over records, skipping the first list which is key names
for values in records[1:]:

    # fresh dict to hold this row
    newdict = {}

    # iterate over each value
    for position,value in enumerate(values):

        # fetch key name from first list in records
        key = records[0][position]
        newdict[key] = value

    # add dict to the list
    transformed_records.append(newdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
from pprint import pprint

records = [['SkuPartNumber', 'ActiveUnits', 'ConsumedUnits'],
           ['EXCHANGESTANDARD', '1', '1'],
           ['O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM', '4', '4']]

fields = records[0]
result = [dict(zip(fields, record)) for record in records[1:]]
pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'ActiveUnits': '1',
  'ConsumedUnits': '1',
  'SkuPartNumber': 'EXCHANGESTANDARD'},
 {'ActiveUnits': '4',
  'ConsumedUnits': '4',
  'SkuPartNumber': 'O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM'}]
```